# How do I detect property changes with RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY in Objective C?

Tags: objective-c, react-native, react-native-ios

```
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE()

- (UIView *)view
{
  return [[RNNativeListview alloc] initWithBridge:self.bridge];
}

RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(rowHeight, float)
RCT_EXPORT_VIEW_PROPERTY(numRows, NSInteger)
```

I want to reload my UITableView whenever js updates numRows.  How do I listen for this?

Answer (score 6):

I don't think that KVO is a good solution.

You can just override setter for numRows property:

```
- (void)setNumRows:(NSInteger)numRows {
    _numRows = numRows;
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Or you can use RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY:

```
RCT_CUSTOM_VIEW_PROPERTY(numRows, NSInteger, RNNativeListview) {
    view.numRows = [RCTConvert NSInteger:json];
    [view.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using an observer.

```
- (instancetype)initWithBridge:(RCTBridge *)bridge {
  [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.numRows" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
  return self;
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context {
  [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```